Why does Next.js middleware only execute on the first redirect and not subsequently?
I am using middleware in Next.js to check user authentication and redirect to the login page if the token is missing. The middleware executes correctly on the first visit to any page, but if I navigate to a page that triggers a redirect, the middleware does not execute again for subsequent redirects to the same page. It only executes again after some time has passed, and then the cycle repeats.
Here is my middleware code:
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import { jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode';
import { TokenUser } from '@/types/common/token-user.type';

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log(request.nextUrl.pathname);

  const token = cookies().get('token');
  if (!token) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/auth/login', request.url));
  }

  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/admin')) {
    const user = jwtDecode<TokenUser>(token.value);

    if (!user.isSuperAdmin)
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/404', request.url));
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|auth).*)'],
};

Why does the middleware in Next.js only execute once for each page and not on subsequent redirects to the same page? How can I ensure the middleware executes on every request, regardless of previous redirects?

If you are taling about the /auth/login redirect, then the middleware is not being called because it's excluded in the matcher config.

@beeef No, I’m referring to a scenario where I navigate from Page A to Page B, and the middleware executes correctly for Page B. However, when I then navigate back from Page B to Page A, the middleware does not execute for Page A. It only runs again after some time has passed, and then the issue repeats. I have excluded the /auth routes from the middleware as I don’t need middleware for those pages.

Just to be sure - are you just clicking the "Back" button in your browser? Because if that's the case, it could be that your browser just shows the cached version of the website instead of sending another request to your server.

For the middleware, there is a config available for which paths it should be executed or not.
According to the official documentation on the Matcher (Next.js Matcher), it looks like you've copied the matcher config from their example and added auth to the regex pattern, for which paths it should not be executed:
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|auth).*)'],
};

Try removing the |auth from the pattern, then it should be executed for any routes that start with /auth.

EDIT: For testing purposes, I've created a completely new Next.js app using create-next-app@latest and I've copied your middleware contents and adjusted it a bit to look something like this:
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log("middleware executed on: ", request.nextUrl.pathname);

  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/test")) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL("/redirected-after-test", request.url)
    );
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|auth).*)"],
};

When I call /test now, I get the following output in my console:
middleware executed on:  /test
middleware executed on:  /redirected-after-test

Which basically means that for every redirect the middleware is executed again - assumed that it is not excluded in your matcher config. On the other hand, if you only do a rewrite, then the middleware is only executed for the "origin" route, not the rewrited one.
So yes, please provide some more information on what paths you think don't work as expected.

I have excluded the /auth routes from the middleware as I don’t need middleware for those pages. The problem is on the routes where it is allowed

Then there has to be another issue with your config or your routes. Check my EDIT please.

What if redirect from /test to /redirected-after-test, and then from /redirected-after-test back to /test ?

I mean I don't have a problem with auth, it goes if the token is not present. The problem is that the middleware is executed once, at the first router transition, and again after some time.

Redirecting from /test to /redirected-after-test and then redirecting back would cause and infinite redirection loop. But yes, the middleware would still be executed for each redirect. A redirect causes another request by the user, which is why the middleware is executed again.

Please provide more information, for which paths you wish the middleware would be executed again after redirecting.
